# I have a problem with configuring SpringMVC, 'org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet' is not assignable to 'jakarta.servlet.Servlet'

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, model-view-controller

web.xml file

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app
        xmlns = "https://jakarta.ee/xml/ns/jakartaee"
        xmlns:xsi = "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:schemaLocation = "https://jakarta.ee/xml/ns/jakartaee https://jakarta.ee/xml/ns/jakartaee/web-app_5_0.xsd"
        version = "5.0"
        metadata-complete = "false">
  <display-name> Welcome to Tomcat</display-name>
  <description> Welcome to Tomcat</description>

  <display-name>spring-cource-mvc-hibernate-aop</display-name>

  <absolute-ordering />

  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
      <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
      <param-value>/WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
  </servlet>

  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>

</web-app>
```

pom.xlm file

```xml
    <dependency>
      <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
      <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
      <version>3.1.0</version>
    </dependency>
```

[image]

I tried to take this advice: Your xml is for servlets version 4.x, which is JavaEE, not JakartaEE. Fix your XML. Also remove the javax.servlet-api dependency and use the jakartaEE version.

I have a problem configuring SpringMVC. An error appears: `org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet` is not assignable to `javax.servlet.Servlet,jakarta.servlet.Servlet`

Comment: You use the spring framework 6 ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can test the use of this dependency :

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>jakarta.servlet</groupId>
    <artifactId>jakarta.servlet-api</artifactId>
    <version>6.0.0</version>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 0):

The pom.xml web-app attribute is set to use jakartaee.

If you are using javax.servlet 3.1 then follow this:

```
<web-app xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd"
    version="3.1">
```